# Machine learning models for time-series?

Tags: r, machine-learning, forecasting

I am trying to make prediction of univariate time series with functions from forecast package like: ets,auto.arima and nnetar.During modeling I divide data in traning and test set.So first I traning models with traning set and after with test set I calculate accuracy and so on so forth.

My goal is to make prediction with machine learning methods but I am little bit confused.Namely my question is does this models are machine learnig models?

I am askng this because I work wit time series which contain daily data.This data have sessonal patern,trend etc.So modelling data with other models (e.g random forest etc) maybe is not good choice because other models are maybe more for cross sectional data.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+daily+ will give you an idea of what can be done with daily data using time series methods that have been automated. Automated modelling is purely machine based thus one could easily refer to it as a machine-based solution insofar as no human input is necessary but optionally can be utilized.

Comment: There is heavy emphasis on anthropomorphic effects including lead and lag effects around events among many other features.

Comment: You can apply common machine learning algorithms to univariate time series by turning relevant temporal and sequential elements into features--for example, values at recent time steps, day of the week, month, etc. For some good discussion, try searching "machine learning time series forecasting" on Google Scholar.